# Excel: Paste Special > Adding a "blank" cell with VBA

Tags: excel, text, numbers, format, zero

I have a large data set that I'm working with in excel.  About 1000+ columns and close to 1 million rows.

My issue is that many of my numbers are formatted as text.  To resolve this, I've been using the copy paste > add technique, adding a blank cell.

My problem is that I'm trying to macro this functionality, but I can't figure out how to add a blank cell.

I tried to get crafty and have the macro create a new row, do the add, then delete that row. But, I can't seem to get that to work either.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using which doesn't quite work?

Comment: There actually was an attempt before OP edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I was looking for.

```
Sub psAdd()

    Dim x As Range 'Just a blank cell for variable
    Dim z As Range 'Selection to work with

    Set z = Cells
    Set x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If x <> "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        x.Copy
        z.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Kill copy mode
    End If
    x.ClearContents 'Back to normal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the entire range, you need to select only the cells with values in them.  I would suggest the Special Cells function:

1. Highlight the cell with the #1 in it and COPY that cell
2. Highlight a column of cells to convert
3. Press **F5 > Goto > Special > Constants** *(you may have to play with the options here to get only the cells you want)*
4. OK *(Now only the cells with values are selected)*
5. Now select **Paste Special > Multiply**

Comment: Thanks for the help Jerry.  I modified the question a bit though.

Comment: The change to the question doesn't seem to change the suggested answer, except maybe step 5 would be **Paste Special > Add**.  The entire technique can be done manually until you're sure it works.  Then you record those steps into a macro and add/edit the resulting code into your main macro.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA you can conditionally convert the target values to doubles (or another type of your choosing).
Tested example below assumes:

1. you are working with `Sheet1` in `ActiveWorkbook`
2. numbers stored as text in column A (1)
3. converted values to appear in column B (2)

An aside: It's probably always a good idea save your work before running VBA. Cheers, and happy coding.

```
Option Explicit

Sub convert_to_dbl()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    For r = 1 To FindLastRow(ws)
        With ws
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(r, 2).Value = CDbl(.Cells(r, 1).Value)
            End If
        End With
    Next r
End Sub

Function FindLastRow(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
        LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End If
    FindLastRow = LastRow
End Function
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating a second row.  With 1000+ rows, any VBA code that I run take quite a while.  So, I need the most efficient method which would be the one that I described.  I just can't get it to work correctly.